# CakePHP 1.3: Security Component Slowing Down Page Load

Tags: security, cakephp

I am trying to add [CakePHP's Security Component](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1296/Security-Component) to my Application, but it slows down page load considerably (ie. if it took 2 seconds to for the server to respond to browser requests, now it takes 7 seconds) and it also prevents .ajax calls. Is there a reason why it is happening this way? Does anyone know how to fix it.

Note that, as soon as I remove Security from the Components list, everything goes back to working as normal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security component breaks any ajax form submissions as it requires a security hash to be passed with the form values. It might work the first time you submit but won't subsequent times.

As for slowing you down, no idea without more information.

Comment: That “security hash” is probably the anti CSRF token.

Comment: I guess I just need to do a little more research into it.. thanks